# WPF: How to make a "pushlike" checkbox?

Tags: wpf, button, checkbox, controltemplate

I would like to make a CheckBox that looks exactly like a button. My initial feeble attempt doesn't work at all.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="test">
    Testing!
    <CheckBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Button>
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Button>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </CheckBox.Template>
</CheckBox>
```

The ContentPresenter isn't working (the button is empty) and when the button is clicked, the IsChecked property does not toggle. Also, I don't know how to make the button look pushed when IsChecked is true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Would a [ToggleButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.aspx) suit your needs?  CheckBox derives from it, and so they are very similar.

Comment: Yes, I had no idea there was already separate class for a CheckBox that looks like a button.

Answer (score 7):

I've just started to write same comment :)

```
<ToggleButton Name="tb"  Height="45" Width="45">
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
```

And now as you wanted, Checkbox control:

```
<CheckBox>
        <CheckBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton">
                </ToggleButton>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True" SourceName="toggleButton">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Content" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
             </ControlTemplate>
        </CheckBox.Template>
    </CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree that ToggleButton is the way to go, but if you want your content to show up in your example, try changing your ContentPresenter declaration to this:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
```

Comment: This works if I change the ControlTemplate declaration to <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">